# iOS - AVFoundation - Endless video recording

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, video-recording

I've implemented a video recorder in my iOS app using AVFoundation's AVAssetWriter (using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput).
Because of file system limitations, the app should record only the last 15minutes. 
When more than 15 minutes passed, the video should start to discard frames in the beginning of the video.

What is the best way to implement this without killing the memory? :)

**EDIT:**
My current idea is to record videos of 1 minute each and merge them in the end. While recording the video, I dismiss irrelevant videos.

Comment: Please check following link. I think useful for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818352/ios-endless-video-recording

Comment: Thanks for the link. Not what I was thinking but manipulation of the mov container might be worth looking into.